# Batch Can't Enter Spaces to a Variable

Tags: file, variables, batch-file, space

Why does it crash if I enter a space when I am entering the message?

The code:

```
:chatter
cls
echo type /help to see chat commands
echo please use: _ instead of spaces(the problem of this code).
set /p message="enter message: "
if %message%==/help goto chatcmds
if %message%==/exit goto chatcmds
if %message%==/changeuser goto chatcmds
echo [%username%]: %message% >> %joinedchat%.chat
goto chatter
```

I just don't see the reason it is not working.
I tried other's suggestions but they don't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to enclose your var and values in quotes because the space is a command separator. I added the /I switch as suggested in the comments to do case insensitive string compares.

```
if /I "%message%"=="/help" goto chatcmds
if /I "%message%"=="/exit" goto chatcmds
if /I "%message%"=="/changeuser" goto chatcmds
```

Comment: Adding the `/i` option to the `if` command might be a good idea.

Comment: @David: Consider enclosing paths/file names in double quotes too. (Unless you are positive that your files/paths can never contain spaces and/or special characters.)